# how to run python code via double click without activate virtualenv myself

Tags: python-3.x

I want to run python code without activate virtualenv myself.

my folder structure like these.

```
main
  |
  |_app.py
  |_virtualenvFolder
       |
       |_Scripts
       |_Lib
```

I have put

```
# virtualenvFolder/Scripts/activate python
```

at the top of my code but it not work
how can I fix this

Answer (score 1):

method#0 put in the beginning of _app.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    def re_open(file,venv):
        import sys
        import os
        import signal
        import subprocess
        exe = os.path.basename(sys.executable)
        print(f'{sys.executable=}')
        if not (exe in ['python.exe','pythonw.exe']):
            return
        python_exe = os.path.abspath(os.path.join( os.path.dirname(file), 
                                                   venv ,'./Scripts/', exe))
        if not os.path.samefile(sys.executable, python_exe):
            try:
                cmd = f'"{python_exe}" "{file}"'
                print(f'{cmd=}')
                py_env = os.environ.copy()
                py_env['PATH']=f'''"{os.path.dirname(python_exe)}";{py_env['PATH']}''' #windows
                p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=py_env) # env=py_env not required
                returncode=p.wait()
                exit(returncode)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                os.kill(p.pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT) #or signal.SIGINT
                exit(1)

    re_open(__file__,venv='./virtualenvFolder') #./virtualenvFolder/Scripts/python.exe
```

method#1 create_a_new_file.py:

```
    import os
    import signal
    import subprocess
    try:
        cmd = "./virtualenvFolder/Scripts/python ./_app.py"
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
        returncode = p.wait()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        os.kill(p.pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
        # os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGINT)
    input('Press Enter to Exit:')
```

Answer (score 0):

simple easy

```
#! virtualenvFolder/Scripts/python
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.